# Erf with complex argument

Tags: power-series, special-functions, error-function

I want to prove that for $a<b$
\begin{align*}
\left\vert erf\left(\sqrt{\pi\gamma+\mathrm{i} a}\right) \right\vert^{2}-\left\vert erf\left(\sqrt{\pi\gamma+\mathrm{i} b}\right) \right\vert^{2}>0,
\end{align*}
where $a,b,\gamma\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$ and
\begin{align*}
erf(z)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{z}e^{-t^2}~dt
\end{align*}
is error function. I tried by series expansion but there is no conclusion at the end.

Answer (score 1):

False.  For $a=1, b=2, \gamma=1$ we get
$$
\left(  \left| {\rm erf} \left(\sqrt {\pi +i}\right) \right| 
 \right) ^{2}- \left(  \left| {\rm erf} \left(\sqrt {\pi +2\,i}\right)
 \right|  \right) ^{2}=- 0.0244743830
$$

Perhaps you didn't write what you meant?